# plot-Bamtools: where are the commands?

Tags: bioinformatics

I would like to visualize my bam file statistics and was told (with no instruction) to use plot-bamstats.
I downloaded bamstats with conda and tried to find a manual or help, but it keeps telling me that bamstats is not a command. I Googled plot-bamstats and found the Github page and another site that tells you how to install bamtools as java.
I am not finding any basic options or descriptions of how to run a simple plot and the documentation is leaving me rather clueless.
My instinct would be to write:

```
plot-bamstats sortedbamfilename.bam
```

or `bamstats optionforplot sortedbamfilename.bam`

With some kind of options in between? I am just not finding any example of code that I can modify to suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `plot-bamstats` in [samtools](https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/develop/misc/plot-bamstats). If this is what you need you could install it with conda and execute it with:

```
conda install -c bioconda samtools gnuplot
samtools stats sortedbamfilename.bam > sortedbamfilename.stats
plot-bamstats -p my_output sortedbamfilename.stats
```

Consider installing packages in a dedicated environment rather than the default one like:

```
conda create -n my_env
conda activate my_env
conda install -c bioconda samtools
```

Comment: Hi! I made the sorted bam stats file and tried to run it like so:
plot-bamstats -p filenameplot filenamesorted.stats

But it gave me this error:
Can't exec "gnuplot": No such file or directory

Comment: @new15b You probably need to install the `gnuplot` program.

Comment: I did and it still didn't work. I wonder if it was my code.  
`plot-bamstats -p filenameplot filenamesorted.stats`  

Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: See edited answer: indeed you need to install gnuplot as well e.g. using `conda install -c bioconda samtools gnuplot` (I guess gnuplot should be a requirement in the samtools recipe of bioconda?). When you say that you installed gnuplot and it doesn't work, how did you install it and what error do you get?